# Vertica :Creating a view

Tags: sql, view, sas, vertica

I'm trying to create a view in Vertica written in SAS.

```
proc sql;
      connect to odbc as try
     (server='10.10.7.174' port=5433 user=dbadmin password=password );
     execute (create view  &schema..myview as 

     ( Select * from &schema..table_1
       union all 
       Select * from &schema..table_2
     ))by try ;

 disconnect from try;
quit;
```

the problem is : as a result it creates a table not a view .

Comment: Your code looks correct from the SAS side. What does the log show? What happens if you run that exact code in Vertica?

Answer (score 1):

DB views will appear as a  `Table` type when SAS Explorer is showing the `Contents of 'libname'` and the libname is remote.

Comment: So it's not posssible to create a view in DB? because it's not only appear as a table but it had the same Characteristics

Comment: Did not say that.  The view in VERTICA will (probably) appear as a table to the SAS client connected (in SAS Explorer).  You can try this SAS SQL statement: `create table WORK.VERTICA_VIEWS as select * from connection to try (select * from VIEWS)` to get a list of the VIEWs according to Vertica server.